# NSPredicate with ANY in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, realm

I have an exception when I use `NSPredicate` in `Realm`:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "ANY phones.number CONTAINS %@)"'
```

Person class:

```
class Person: RLMObject {
    ...
    dynamic var phones = RLMArray(objectClassName: Phone.className())
}
```

Phone class:

```
class Phone: RLMObject {

    dynamic var number = ""
    dynamic var formattedNumber = ""

}
```

And phone predicate constructed:

```
func phonesPredicate(#searchString:String) -> NSPredicate {

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY phones.number CONTAINS %@)", searchString)

return searchPredicate
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a stray closing parenthesis in your format string.